# Can someone give me an example on how to use React Widget's DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, datetimepicker

I don't know if it's me or if these instructions are terrible - but I am having real trouble using this date time picker library.

I am trying to learn how to implement this library into my project: http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/

On my Max I have downloaded Node.js and NPM, and I ran the command, looked inside my ‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨usr⁩ ▸ ⁨local⁩ ▸ ⁨lib⁩ ▸ ⁨node_modules⁩ folder and grabbed the dist folder, which contains react-widgets.js and put it into my file directory for my web project (seemed like a lot of unnecessary work in this day and age)

Where can I get those other two files listed on the website:

```
<script src="react-15.5.5.js"></script>
<script src="react-dom-15.5.0.js"></script>
```

And how do I even invoke the Date Time Picker? The documentation is SO POOR.

Any advise pointing me in the right direction would be really welcomed. A codepen would be AMAZING.

Edit:

This is as far as I was able to get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>grdgsrdg test</title>
<link href="dist/css/react-widgets.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body translate="no">
<div id="root"></div>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js'></script>
<script src='dist/react-widgets.js'></script>
<script id="rendered-js">
var DropdownList = ReactWidgets.DropDownlist;

  ReactDOM.render(<DropdownList/>, document.getElementById('app-root'))
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and nothing works, that's just from following the directions.

Answer (score 0):

> A simple and reusable datepicker component for React.

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
  );
};
```